# What is the proper adjective for keep looking for long time?

Tags: meaning, verbs, adjectives, adverbs

What is the proper adjective that best describe the way a person keeps looking at any other person or object so that as if his eye is about to get out.

As an example, when a man keeps looking at a beautiful lady for a long time without even twitching. Sometimes it might be considered an *envious look* or sometimes it might be due to profound admiration

Comment: Well, he's *staring*.  You could say "the staring gentleman", though it would be more idiomatic to say "the gentleman who is staring".  (If his mouth is open and he's drooling, though, he's *leering*.)

Comment: @HotLicks can i say pop-eyed

Comment: @Elpharaoh - That could be confused with the cartoon character in conversation.  I have heard things like, “He was staring so hard his eye(s) about fell out of his head.”

Comment: Yes, you could say something like "he stared pop-eyed".  There might be some who were confused by the cartoon character, but likely not many.

Comment: Please write an example sentence where the word would be used. The following is the strict guideline of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: The term "goggle-eyed" used to be popular, but anymore is apt to be taken for "Google-eyed".

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Questions that invite many equally valid answers are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Spellbinding- adj- Holding one’s attention completely as though by magic; fascinating.

Entralling- adj- Capturing and holding one’s attention; fascinating.

Transfix- verb- (usually be transfixed) Cause (someone) to become motionless with horror, wonder, or astonishment.

Those three are the first to come to mind. 
(sorry cannot post more than three links, but all definitions came from [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us).)

Comment: can i say pop-eyed

Comment: @Elpharaoh Surely if it's what you are meaning. See [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pop%20eye).

Answer (score 0):

I would say **[fixedly.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/fixedly)**

It means to maintain the eyes unwaveringly focused on a subject.

> But now Pasha was [staring fixedly](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=08YocI7JqlUC&pg=PA53&dq=%22staring%20fixedly%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22staring%20fixedly%22&f=false) at the floor--and at one specific spot.